# Publishing approval workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, publishing, content

I need to design a **Publishing Approval Workflow** for Pages Library `OOTB` for **SharePoint 2013** on premise environment using SharePoint Designer.

There should be three approvals

1. QA
2. Manager
3. Finance Manager.

I need to understand where I should add these approvals. I started publishing with following line of code.

```
Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item
```

Should I add my 3 Approval Process after this? Will the document still be in the draft mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two kind of approval workflow

- Serial
- Parallel

Your Document should be in draft mode when you have single approval workflow with multiple participate. But you can add multiple approval workflow with individual participate in which you can perform CheckIn and CheckOut operation on document. Both are relay on your requirements.

You should go through Microsoft documentation.

[Link1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-A24BCD14-0E3C-4449-B936-267D6C478579) [Link2](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078C5A89-821F-44A9-9530-40BB34F9F742) [link3](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-core-solutions-jump-start-8262?l=bSwfjnKy_8204984382)

Comment: Is there any specific step to keep the document in Draft Mode?

Comment: Workflow should do internally.